# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error when installing stock ICS Launcher on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, galaxy, android-launcher

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and I've built the stock AOSP ICS Launcher2 app. I then tried to install the apk via "adb install" but I get an "INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT" error when I do that. The device logcat is as follows:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): setted country_code = France
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): setted countryiso_code = FR
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): setted sales_code = XEF
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): readGMSProperty: start
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): readGMSProperty: end
D/LibQmg_native( 5431): register_android_app_LibQmg
D/AndroidRuntime( 5431): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
W/PackageManager( 2093): verifying app can be installed or not
I/ApplicationPolicy( 2093): isApplicationInstallationEnabled
D/dalvikvm( 2093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7885K, 31% free 32346K/46791K, paused 2ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm( 2093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1834K, 31% free 32555K/46791K, paused 3ms+5ms
E/PackageManager( 2093): Package XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX has mismatched uid: 10130 on disk, 10131 in settings
I/PackageManager( 2093): Running dexopt on: XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX
I/PackageManager( 2093): Linking native library dir for |XXXX|XXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX
W/dalvikvm( 5442): DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/com.android.launcher-1.apk' does not include classes.dex
W/installd( 1907): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.android.launcher-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
E/installd( 1907): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.launcher-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
W/PackageManager( 2093): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.android.launcher-1.apk
```

What could I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the Android emulator's memory capacity, there are 2 ways for that:

1- Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" then go to "Run Configurations..." locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.

2- Go to Eclipse's Preferences, then Select “Launch” Add “-partition-size 1024” on the “Default emulator option” field, then click “Apply” and use your emulator as usual.